# Is this a valid way of implementing a continuous element into the sentence regarding "ashamed"?

Tags: progressive-aspect

"He should be ashamed to be laughing at his friends with the bullies."

I am quite aware that usually and most of the time the adjective ashamed is followed by "of doing", yet can that be substituted with "to be doing" in order to imply a progressive action?

Comment: It's unclear who should be doing the shaming. Perhaps just "He should be ashamed laughing at his friends alongside the bullies." Or you may want to use "He should be ashamed *of himself* laughing at his friends with the bullies."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine.  You are saying "*While he is laughing*, he should be ashamed", and this is a valid sentiment and a valid way to write it.

Comment: I think 'of' is the most tense-less, with 'to be' close by, but 'while' adds a durative constraint.

Comment: It really is not fine. To be ashamed of something in English, verb or noun.

Comment: Really, really not fine. Terrible, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can use *to* instead of *of* as a preposition in the sentence with **ashamed**.

- I'm ashamed to say that the apple is not fit to eat.
- He should be ashamed to be laughing.
- He should be ashamed to laugh at his friends.
- To be laughing at his friends with the bullies, he should be ashamed.
- **He should be ashamed, to be laughing at his friends with the bullies.**

A comma was needed, to make the sentence more comprehensible. Also the suggestion given in the first answer was actually very good, too.